# When socket select blocks is it waiting on the server?

Tags: java, sockets, select, network-programming, socketchannel

When a select call on a write channel blocks, is it waiting on the server to respond?  Or is it just waiting for the network to respond.

```
SocketChannel sChannel;
Selector selector;
SelectionKey selectionKey;
...
selector = Selector.open();
selectionKey =  sChannel.register(selector, 0);
selectionKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
selector.select(timeout*1000);
```

Comment: What would it mean for a network to "respond"?

Comment: @immibis I guess I am wondering if it the client side getting ready to send or the server side getting ready to receive.

Answer (score 0):

> When a select call on a write channel blocks, is it waiting on the server to respond?

When a `select()` call *on a channel registered only for `OP_WRITE`,* like your example, blocks, it is waiting for space in the socket send buffer, which in turn is waiting for space in the receiver's socket receive buffer, which in turn is waiting for the peer to *read*.